# Prime number aligning

Tags: java

I can't get this code to align correctly. I need it to display in 5 rows of ten, aligned neatly. This is what i have, please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main(String...args) { //start main method
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in ); //renamed Scanner to sc
        int a = 1; // first prime number
        int b = 227; // 50th prime number
        System.out.println(" ");

        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) //this is the primer for the prime number formula
        {
            boolean isPrime = true; //sets the statement to true
            if (isPrime) for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) //formula to get the prime
            {
                if (i != j && i % j == 0) //formula checking prime
                isPrime = false; //sets statement to false
            }
            if (isPrime) {

                System.out.print(i + " "); //if true it prints prime number
                System.out.printf("\n "); //if false it prints a dash

            }
        }

    } //end of main method
} //end of class
```

Comment: Do you want to align it?thats all.

Comment: Yes because i think i got the rest of the code right. i got it to display the first 50 prime numbers, but i just need to align them in 5 rows of 10.

Comment: You could start by indenting your code correctly ;) Then keep track of the number of primes you printed and if it's a multiple of 10, then print a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a `counter` variable which you will increment once you print a prime number.If `counter%10 returns 0` then you can add a new line.

```
//initialize counter with 0
...
if (isPrime)
{

System.out.print(i+" ");//if true it prints prime number
counter++;
if(counter%10==0)
System.out.println();//it will add a new line
 }
...
```